# How can I simplify this typedef different switch statement?

Tags: c++, coding-style, switch-statement

I am doing a switch statement over a char, and oftentimes the only difference between, say, `'A'` and `'a'` is certain static constants i have in a particular struct and a random numeric constant. Here is an example:

```
switch(someChar)
{
case 'A':
{
    typedef structWithConstants<caseA, UPCASE> constantsT;
    someStruct s;
    s.bla = bla;
    s.foo = getfoo7(rat+constantsT::rat);
    s.other = getOther10(other + constantsT::other);

    someFunctionBar(&s);
}
break;
case 'a':
{
    typedef structWithConstants<caseA, LOWCASE> constantsT;
    someStruct s;
    s.bla = bla;
    s.foo = getfoo3(rat+constantsT::rat);
    s.other = getOther10(other + constantsT::other);

    someFunctionBar(&s);
}
break;
}
```

so in the above, literally the only difference in terms of code is the constantsT which gets used and the 7 switched to a three...is there a way to simplify the repetitive code above a bit? Maybe collapsing some of the common behavior between both cases?

Comment: If there's no `break`, a case falls through to the next. You might be able to use that to help organize, but I don't think it's the best option. Functions are more suited for eliminating repetitive code.

Comment: Do `getfooX` take different parameters (as types), or they may have the same type, but different body?

Comment: I guess you could use a (devil) macro, but it's kinda error-prone and ugly, according to most of the C++ developers. I, personally, would use, if I can't figure out any C++-ish way to do this, using tempatlates and probably functors.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done with templates and functors, but I need more code to try to do it. How is `structWithConstants` defined? What is `constantsT::rat`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible to template a function, declare a type for those 'foo'-s, and then pass the  casing template param to some caller function

```
typedef int getfootype(char c);

template<getfootype f,char CASING>
void  handle(char c)
{
        typedef structWithConstants<caseA, CASING> constantsT;
        someStruct s;
        s.bla = bla;
        s.foo = f(rat+constantsT::rat);
        s.other = getOther10(other + constantsT::other);

        someFunctionBar(&s);
}

switch(someChar)
{
    case 'A':
          handle<getfoo7,UPCASE>(someChar);
       break;
    case 'a':
          handle<getfoo3,LOWCASE>(someChar);
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like that:

```
switch(someChar)
{
case 'A':
case 'a':
{
    typedef structWithConstants<caseA, UPCASE> constantsT_UP;
    typedef structWithConstants<caseA, LOWCASE> constantsT_LO;
    someStruct s;
    s.bla = bla;
    if (someChar == 'a')
      s.foo = getfoo3(rat+constantsT_LO::rat);
     else
    s.foo = getfoo7(rat+constantsT_UP::rat);
    s.other = getOther10(other + (someChar == 'a') ? constantsT_LO::other : constantsT_UP::other);

    someFunctionBar(&s);
}
break;
}
```

but it looks quite complicated...

Comment: I thought about this but I want to avoid the if inside of there..id be adding an extra branch to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Place the repeating parts outside of `switch`:

```
someStruct s;
s.bla = bla;

switch(someChar)
{
case 'A':
    typedef structWithConstants<caseA, UPCASE> constantsT;
    s.foo = getfoo7(rat+constantsT::rat);
break;
case 'a':
    typedef structWithConstants<caseA, LOWCASE> constantsT;    
    s.foo = getfoo3(rat+constantsT::rat);
break;
}

s.other = getOther10(other + constantsT::other);
someFunctionBar(&s);
```

Comment: Again - the `typedef`s are different, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    switch(someChar)
    {
    case 'A': case 'a' :
    {
        typedef structWithConstants<caseA, UPCASE> constantsT;
        someStruct s;
        s.bla = bla;
        if(someChar == 'A')
            s.foo = getfoo7(rat+constantsT::rat);
        else if(someChar == 'a')
            s.other = getOther10(other + constantsT::other);

        someFunctionBar(&s);

        s.foo = getfoo3(rat+constantsT::rat);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: The `typedef`s are different, too. And if this is for, let's say 2*26 `char`s.. it would be a `switch` inside a `switch`. switchception :D

Comment: @KirilKirov You are right, that could be included in the if as well.